# How to restore the selectedIndex of a FlipView

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm trying to implement the save and restore status of a flipview. In order to explain the problem I simplified this example:

I start with two buttons in the UI, one add a new item to a ObservableCollection and the other navigates to another page:

```
private ObservableCollection<String> items = new ObservableCollection<String>();

public TestPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
    this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;
    DefaultViewModel["Items"] = items;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    items.Add("Test " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"));
}

private void Button_Click_Page2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
}

...
```

In the xaml I define the following FlipView:

```
<FlipView x:Name="MyFlipView" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Now I want to save the status of the page when I leave it (saving the items and the current position)

```
private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
{
    e.PageState["Items"] = items;
    e.PageState["Selected"] = MyFlipView.SelectedIndex;
}
```

And (here comes the problem) restore it when I return to the page:

```
private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PageState != null)
    {
        DefaultViewModel["Items"] = e.PageState["Items"];
        /*CRASHES*/ MyFlipView.SelectedIndex = (int)e.PageState["Selected"];
    }
}
```

When I try to restore the SelectedIndex the app crashes with a `Value does not fall within the expected range`.

I think it is because at this point the FlipView has not loaded the restored items. How can I solve that?

Comment: I'm not sure (I've not tried), but maybe you can in *NavigationHelper_LoadState* store the *Selected* value to a variable, and set FlipView's index once it's loaded.

Comment: Thanks. How can I know exactly when it's loaded?

Comment: Do this in the Loaded event handler

Comment: Try in *Page.Loaded* event or *FlipView.Loaded* one. You may also try with *FlipView.Items.VectorChanged* event - as I think it should be fired once *Items* property has changed, which may be suitable to set *FlipView's* index. I'm not quite sure now what happens first - *LoadState* event or *Loaded*, thus it's a matter of trying some things.